# do we have to deploy staticfiles folder to heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

When I follow some tutorial on the web, there is **staticfiles** folder included in **.gitignore** file. Although when I included it in **.gitignore** file it is deployed to heroku server. I can see that folder in my main directory. Then why is it included in **.gitignore** file?

Answer (score 2):

you dont commit your `static` folder to version control, you normally make another `site-static` folder for your css, js and img. it is simply because there are many other static files coming from e.g. django admin which lands into `static` folder if you do `collectstatic`. after `collectstatic` you will see many other static files of django apps / another installed apps which makes it hard to manage your own static files. thats why you need to `ignore` static folder and work locally in your `site-static` folder

***I can see that folder in my main directory***: that folder came from `collectstatic` command which collects all static files into `static` folder.

dont forget to make:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'site-static'),
)
```

Comment: wait I confused. I dont create **staticfiles** folder. I only created manually **static** folder in my main directory. But when I run `heroku run bash` and `ls` command, I also see **staticfiles** folder too along my **static** folder.

Comment: then **staticfiles** folder is created automatically through the command **collectstatic**. And I should not include it in **.gitignore** file right?

Comment: No. Even I did not created **staticfiles** folder it is there on heroku. I wonder where it came from?

Comment: @MaksimKevin right. include only ``*/static/*`` into ignore file.

Comment: @MaksimKevin if you defined staticfiles_dir, it will be created on heroku, but just wont be used.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku looks for all folders named `static` in your project and copies all asset files from these folders to `staticfiles` on heroku. You don't need to manually create and push the `staticfiles` folder to heroku. It is created automatically.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```